# Why $ \sum_{t=2}^T \frac{1}{t^{\alpha-1}} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha-2} $?

Tags: inequality

Any idea how to prove: 
$$
\sum_{t=2}^T \frac{1}{t^{\alpha-1}} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha-2}
$$

(*) from page 5 of [this](http://www.shivani-agarwal.net/Teaching/E0370/Aug-2013/Lectures/22.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha\gt 2$. The sum is less than 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t^{\alpha-1}}.$$
This integral is $\frac{1}{\alpha-2}$.